# Python - Tkinter - Label text from StringVar does not display/update

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to convert a simple command line program I've written previously to have a GUI. Before starting to add things to my existing/working code, I wanted to play around with just building the GUI in Tkinter. I finally started making progress as far as getting things to show up how I want them to, until I get to widgets that I want to have their display text change depending on the contents of a variable.

From what I've read here and in various sets of documentation, the way to do this is with a `StringVar`, which I've attempted to do, but when I run the program, the text for the `status_msg` Label widget doesn't show up at all. I tried putting a set() call to update the variable in several places, and while it appears to update the variable, the label doesn't show up in the window at all. Finally I tried adding a function that the "Add Key" button calls to force the set call and try to make the label show up, but it still doesn't work, though it does print exactly what I expect to the console.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

numkeys = 0
keystring = str(numkeys) + " entries ready for parsing"
class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.numkeys = tk.StringVar()
        self.numkeys.set(keystring)

        api_frame = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Key Entry", padx = 5, pady = 5)
        api_frame.grid(padx = 10, pady = 10)
        key1_lbl = tk.Label(api_frame, text = "Entry 1:", anchor = tk.W)
        key1_lbl.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.key = tk.Entry(api_frame, width = 18)
        self.key.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        key2_lbl = tk.Label(api_frame, text="Entry 2:")
        key2_lbl.grid(row = 0, column = 2, padx = 5)
        self.key2 = tk.Entry(api_frame, width = 45)
        self.key2.grid(row = 0, column = 3, padx = 2, columnspan = 3)
        status_msg = tk.Label(api_frame, textvariable = self.numkeys.get())
        status_msg.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 3)
        btn_submit = tk.Button(api_frame, text="Add Key", width = 12, command = self.test)
        btn_submit.grid(row = 1, column = 4, pady = 5)
        btn_start = tk.Button(api_frame, text="Parse Keys", width = 12, command = None)
        btn_start.grid(row = 1, column = 5, pady = 5)

        #self.numkeys.set(keystring)

    def test(self):
        self.numkeys.set(keystring)
        root.update_idletasks()
        print("test function ran")
        print(app.numkeys.get())

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.master.title('Tk test')
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
textvariable = self.numkeys.get()
```

by

```
textvariable = self.numkeys
```

Comment: That did it! I feel a little stupid after seeing how simple that was, but very much not complaining. Thanks!